# Help to express this proposition using predicates and quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Video on demand can be delivered when there are at least 8 megabytes of memory is available and connection speed is at least 56 kbps.

I can understand that this proposition is in form (M∧C)→V where

M is at least 8 mb memory is available

C is connection speed is at least 56 kbps

V is video on demand can be delivered

But how can I convert M,C and V into predicates and how can I express this statement using quantifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st step: reformulate the statement in a quantifier-like form:

> Every video on demand can be delivered if there are at least 8 megabytes of memory and there is a connection speed of at least 56 kbps.

2nd step: identify suitable predicates:

> $\text {VideoDemand}(x), \text {Deliv}(x), \text {m8Mem}(y), \text {k56Conn}(z)$.

*Things may be different if you want to use numerical values*...

Having said that, we may have:

> $\forall x \ [\text {VideoDemand}(x) \to (\exists y \exists z (\text {m8Mem}(y) \land \text {k56Conn}(z)) \to \text {Deliv}(x))]$.

Comment: Thank you , sir.